# Searching a complicated string

Tags: vb.net, string, search

I am looking for a way to search this string of information.

```
<a href="CLSID/70545-GoogleToolbar_32_dll.html">Google Side Bar</a></td><td>GoogleToolbar_32.dll</td>
```

I am able to search for the keyword

```
<td>GoogleToolbar_32.dll</td>
```

From there I need to get the phrase "CLSID/70545-GoogleToolbar_32_dll.html". My idea was to search backwards to find the next occurring "a href", search until the ending quotation mark. But I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to parse HTML. Take a look into [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off thing or you know the formatting will be consistent, you could use a regular expression. The example below will do what you asked. This isn't particularly robust, but it will work for your example. Regular expressions are not what you want to use for parsing markup languages in general. As Neolisk said, you may wish to look into a parsing library.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

   Sub Main()

      Dim html As String = "<html><body><table><tr><td><a href=""CLSID/70545-GoogleToolbar_32_dll.html"">Google Side Bar</a></td><td>GoogleToolbar_32.dll</td></tr></table></body></html>"
      Debug.WriteLine(GetClsId(html))

   End Sub

   Function GetClsId(html As String) As String
      Const rx As String = "<a href=""(?<clsid>.*)"">.*<td>GoogleToolbar_32.dll</td>"
      Dim m As Match

      m = Regex.Match(html, rx)
      If m.Success Then
         Return m.Groups.Item("clsid").Value
      Else
         Return Nothing
      End If

   End Function

End Module
```